# Typescript - set data from Observable to an attribute

Tags: typescript, observable, angularfire2, angular5

I'm trying to extract data from an Observable result from AngularFireDatabase.object() call and set it to an attribute to use it later in others scopes.

```
export class QuizzEditComponent implements OnInit {
  private quizzRef: any;
  private quizzObject: any;
  private key: string;

  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.key = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.quizzRef = this.database.object(environment.firebase.databaseName+'/'+this.key);
    this.quizzRef.valueChanges().forEach(line => {
      this.quizzObject = line;
      console.log(this.quizzObject); // this display the wanted object
    });
    console.log(this.quizzObject); // This display undefined
  }
}
```

I tried different iteration like `for let line of this.quizzItem` doesn't work since Observable is an object !

Any ideas !

Comment: `this.quizzObject` does not get set until the value changes...

Comment: it get set inside the `forEach` iteration ! even if I add a timeout `setTimeout(function(){console.log(this.quizzObject);}, 1000);` outside the `forEach` it display undefined !

Comment: @Moghreb, you can consider calling a function upon your variable `this.quizzObject` is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, `this.quizzObject` it filled after a while (Async Scope), this is why the second `console.log()` display undefined.

The solution is to initialize `this.quizzObject` by empty data and create a formBuilder then manage it into the template using `(ngModel)`.

Component :

```
init(){
  this.key = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.initObject();
  this.quizzRef = this.database.object(environment.firebase.databaseName+'/'+this.key);
  this.quizzItem = this.quizzRef.valueChanges().subscribe(item => {
    this.quizzObject = item;
  });
}

initObject(){
  this.quizzObject = [];
  this.quizzObject.question = "";
  this.quizzObject.reponses = [{1: "", 2: "", 3: "", "correctAnswer": ""}];

  this.quizzForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    question: [this.quizzObject.question, Validators.required],
    reponses: this.formBuilder.group({
      1: this.quizzObject.reponses[1],
      2: this.quizzObject.reponses[2],
      3: this.quizzObject.reponses[3],
      correctAnswer: this.quizzObject.reponses.correctAnswer
    }),
  });
}
```

Template :

```
<form [formGroup]="quizzForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" role="form">
              <div class="form-group has-success">
              <div class="card bg-light mb-3">

                  <div class="card-header">

                    <label class="form-control-label" for="question">Question</label>

                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <input formControlName="question" type="text" class="form-control form-control-success" id="inputSuccess" [(ngModel)]="quizzObject.question" required>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
```

This is not the best way to do it but it resolved my issue (y)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a problem related to how you are setting your data inside your component. From your code, if you expect to get the last element of your observable, one way to do it, can be to call a function after your variable was set. This way, you ensure that your variable `this.quizzObject` is not undefined within your function that is called.

```
export class QuizzEditComponent implements OnInit {
  private quizzRef: any;
  private quizzObject: any;
  private key: string;

  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.key = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.quizzRef = this.database.object(environment.firebase.databaseName+'/'+this.key);
    this.quizzRef.valueChanges().forEach(line => {
      this.quizzObject = line;
      console.log(this.quizzObject); // this display the wanted object
      this.myFunction()
    });

    myFunction(){
      //do all the computation here to the last element return by the observable
      console.log(this.quizzObject); 
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `push` to store data like this

```
private quizzObject=[];
```

and instead of `this.quizzObject = line;` try `this.quizzObject.push(line);`